Did any attendees write up accounts of pre-1980 Homebrew Computer Club meetings?
Per Wikipedia, "The Homebrew Computer Club was an early computer hobbyist group in Menlo Park, California, which met from March 1975 to December 1986."
I'm looking for written accounts or similar documentation of any of the pre-1980 meetings by those who attended. And video would be interesting, too, though I doubt any exists.

You might be interested in their newsletters, which are available here: https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102740021

That link also answers the question in the negative. "The only extensive contemporaneous records are these...".

It seems that archive.org has a couple more of the newsletter.

Along with the newsletters mentioned in comments, the Computer History Museum has some oral history interviews with early members of the club, such as Lee Felsenstein and Larry Tesler (Linked to interview 2/3 because that's when the club comes up).
They also have a landing page "The Homebrew Computer Club" in their exhibition section which has links to other resources (like contemporary articles mentioning the club).
As was also mentioned in the comments, the internet archive appears to have more of the newsletters than CHM (or is organizing them differently, 26 items vs CHM's 18).
In 2023 there was a reunion of some members of the club, with a 2024 write-up in The New Stack.
There are two videos (one and two) on youtube of this meeting which are linked from the above article. There may be more out there (the uploader makes a comment about parts 2 and 3 on their patreon).
